# NoReverseMatch at /. Reverse for 'topic' with arguments '('',)' not found

Tags: python, django

I'm doing Django tutorial that creates a website that keeps a journal.

When I run my website, I found this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /topics/

Reverse for 'topic' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['topics/(?P<topic_id>[0-9]+)/$']
```

The code usually works well

This is my link to the page:

```
<a href="{%url 'learning_logs:topics' %}">Topics</a>
```

This is my url patterns:

```
# Page that shows all topics
path('topics/', views.topics, name='topics'),
# Page that shows individual topic
path('topics/<int:topic_id>/', views.topic, name='topic')
```

The link should be matched with `path('topics/', views.topics, name='topics')`
, but from the error message django tried to match it with `path('topics/<int:topic_id>/', views.topic, name='topic')`

This is my view:

```
def topics(request):
    """Provide all topics"""
    topics = Topic.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)
```

This is my template:

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <p>Topics</p>

  <ul>
    {% for topic in topics %}
      <li> 
        <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a> 
      </li>
    {% empty %}
      <p>No topic have been added yet.</p>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  
  <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:new_topic' %}">Add a New Topic</a>

{% endblock content %}
```

The code isn't working since I wrote my last code. And the last code doesn't influence this link/page.

This is my last code:

```
#Page for adding new entry
path('new_entry/<int:topic_id>/', views.new_entry, name='new_entry')
```

.

```
def new_entry(request, topic_id):
#Enter a new entry for a topic
topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)

if request.method != 'POST':
    #No data submitted; Retrieve blank form 
    form = EntryForm()
else:
    #Process the data
    form = EntryForm(data=request.POST) 
    if form.is_valid:
        new_entry = form.save(commit=False) 
        new_entry.topic = topic
        form.save()
        return redirect('learning_logs:topic', topic_id=topic_id) 

context = {'topic': topic, 'form': form}
return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_entry.html', context)
```

.

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <p>New Entry For <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' %}">{{ topic }}</a> Topic</p>

  <p>Add a New Entry:</p>

  <form action="{% url 'learning_logs:new_topic' topic.id %}" method='POST'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button name='submit'>Add Entry</button>
  </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

Thank you for reading!!!

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: It works now. I think the error might be from Django because the code is still the same

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is coming from

```
{% url 'learning_logs:topic' %}
```

You need to include the topic id. It looks like you could do:

```
{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that in your two paths you have one pointing to the `views.topic` view and one to the `views.topics` view (i.e. with an s at the end). You only post one view (`topics`), so I'm assuming that you have made a typo? If you fix that your problem should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the in-correct use of your topic view, lacking of the topic-id argument.

in your new_entry.html:

```
  <p>New Entry For <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' %}">{{ topic }}</a> Topic</p>
```

should be:

```
  <p>New Entry For <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a></p>
```